# Node-Red sends a message "require" is not defined

Tags: node-red

In the function node, customize the message sending mechanism, but require is not defined.

[image]

Comment: There isn't a question here, just a statement.

Comment: Also please do not post images of text, post the actual text and format it properly. Images are hard to read and impossible for people that use screen readers.

Comment: Why are you trying to create a MQTT connection in a function node rather than use the built in MQTT nodes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['require' keyword doesn't work within Node Red Function node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36756858/require-keyword-doesnt-work-within-node-red-function-node)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Details of how to load external modules for use in the Function Node are covered in the Node-RED Getting Started Guide [here](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/writing-functions#loading-additional-modules)

There are 2 options

1. Adding the node to the `functionGlobalContext` by editing the `settings.js` file. e.g.

   ```js
   functionGlobalContext: {
     osModule:require('os')
   }
   ```

   Then load it in the function node with

   ```js
   var os = global.get('osModule');
   ```
2. Enabling `functionExternalModules` in `settings.js`, this will enable the ability to configure external modules in the function node editor. This feature is new in the 1.3.x release.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I have added and modified settings.js as above, and there will be no "require" error, but there will be another error: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have solved the problem, completed the above steps, and restarted Node-Red.