# Using playwright within Node Red

Tags: playwright, node-red

I'm trying to use playwright on a raspberry pi B to generate a screenshot of a web page.

The .js file runs fine

```js
const { chromium } = require('playwright');

(async () => {
  const browser = await chromium.launch({
    headless: true
  });
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.wikipedia.org/');
  await page.screenshot({path:'wiki.png'})

  // ---------------------
  await context.close();
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Ideally I'd like to do this within NodeRed, but pasting the code into a function block produces:

```
11/8/2023, 2:24:40 PMnode: function 1
function : (error)
"ReferenceError: require is not defined (line 2, col 22)"
```

Is that an easy fix? Alternatively how do I execute the javascript file from within Nodered?

Tried pasting code within function block... got error
Also tried adding the  node-red-contrib-playwright node, but I can't see any documentation and it wont add any nodes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['require' keyword doesn't work within Node Red Function node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36756858/require-keyword-doesnt-work-within-node-red-function-node)

Comment: I've tried removing the 'const { chromium } = require('playwright');' line, but the rest of the code produces several syntax errors. 
On the positive side, I can use the exec node to run the external javascript, so I can get my screenshot. I'd rather have kept all the code within node-red though.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't use node red, just Playwright, so I probably can't help, but I would share those errors and consider [edit]ing them into your post along with your attempt at removing the `require` to make it easier for a node red enthusiast to help.

Answer (score 0):

The node-red documentation covers this [here](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/writing-functions#loading-additional-modules)

You have 2 choices

1. Edit the `settings.js` file to add the playwright module to the global context. You will need to use `global.get('playwright')` instead of `require('playwright')`
2. Add playwright to the Setup tab of the function node and use `const chromium = playwright.chromium`